# How to install Intel XDK IDE on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: intel

How can install intel XDK IDE on Ubuntu 14.04

When I install Intel XDK IDE this error is shown:

[image: Error page returned during installation]

Comment: Install using install.sh and not with install_GUI.sh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download  Intel(R) XDK from the link http://xdk-software.intel.com

The filename is `xdk_web_linux64_master_0277.tgz`

Extract the file into a temporary directory probably `~/temp`. The root of the compressed file has a single directory called `xdk_web_linux64`, so you don't need to create a separate directory.

In your terminal go to the directory `~/temp/xdk_web_linux64`

```
cd ~/temp/xdk_web_linux64
```

Explore the directory with `ls` command and check for the file install.sh

Install using the install.sh script. It should work fine

```
./install.sh
```

Hope this helps!